# deserializing Objects with private constructors from JSONArray by Jackson annotations using external class for creating objects

Tags: json, polymorphism, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, private-constructor

I'm trying to deserialize Objects (with private constructors) from JSONArray by Jackson annotations using external class for creating objects.

Class
Vehicle

Subclasses with private constructor
Car
Bike
Motocycle

External class
CarCreator
with method createBike, createMotocycle, createCar

The error I got since now:
Cannot construct instance of  (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

I can't find a way to create Subclasses by external Class.